# How do I find the value in one dataframe column in the row with the maximum value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, max

Given a dataframe with columns `price` and `make` (among others) for cars,
I need to find the make of the car that is the most expensive. I found the highest price using max(df['price']) but now I don't know how to use that price to find the make that correlates to it. Sample data can be found at this csv link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/imports-85.csv

Comment: Just did `df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/imports-85.csv"); max(df['price'])` and got a valid result. BTW the pandas way to do it is `df.price.max()`

Comment: These are two separate questions. **(1.)** why the max() function in pandas gave me 'Nan'value? **(2.)** I don't know how to use that price to find the make that correlates to it.

Comment: @TomRon TIL `pandas.read_csv` accepts a web URI, not just a local path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to find the value in the `make` column from the row with the max value in column `price`:

```py
make = df.loc[df.price.idxmax(),'make']
```

Output:

```
mercedes-benz
```

Explanation:

- use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to find the index of the maximum value in the `price` column ignoring `NaN` (this is default behavior based on `skipna` argument defaulting to `True` as indicated in the docs)
- use `loc[]` to access the dataframe value in column `make` at the above index.

Comment: Do need any additional help with your question?